# Como faço uma divisão inteira?

Tags: javascript

Usando ruby, a divisão de dois números inteiros é uma divisão inteira, isso é, o resultado é um número inteiro. Por exemplo:

```
3/2
=> 1
```

Se desejo que o resultado seja um numero decimal, posso utilizar um numero flutuante ao invés de um inteiro:

```
3.0/2
=> 1.5
```

Como posso fazer uma divisão inteira que funcione parecida com a de ruby em javascript?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Comecemos por uma divisão normal:

```
var result = 3/2;
```

Conforme observou, esta operação tem resultado `1.5`, que não é o que queremos.

Para ter uma divisão inteira, temos de decidir que tipo de arredondamento pretendemos usar.

As principais opções são:

- Arredondar para baixo (*por defeito*). É esta a [forma de arredondamento que o Ruby utiliza](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16530579/32775).
- Arredondar para o número mais próximo.
- Arredondar para cima (*por excesso*).
- Truncar o resultado (arredondar para baixo para números positivos, para cima para  números negativos). Esta forma de arredondamento é muito comum na divisão inteira de outras linguagens de programação, como o C.

Exemplo:

```
var arredondadoParaBaixo = Math.floor(3/2);
var arredondadoParaProximo = Math.round(3/2);
var arredondadoParaCima = Math.ceil(3/2);
```

Para truncar o resultado, temos mais de uma forma. A função [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) foi introduzida no ECMAScript 6 (norma recente do JavaScript), mas esta função é bastante recente pelo que não é universalmente suportada pelos navegadores de Internet.

Uma forma alternativa de truncar é "forçar" o nº a ser inteiro. Uma das formas mais simples de fazer isto é usar operações bit-a-bit, mas que não façam nada.

```
var truncado = (3/2)|0;
```

Isto faz a operação OU bit-a-bit com o número 0.

O "OU" converte o número para inteiro antes de realizar a operação mas, de resto, OU com 0 é como soma com 0 ou multiplicação com 1 -- não faz nada.

Outras formas usadas incluem o `~~(3/2)`, o `(3/2)^0`, o `(3/2)<<0` e o `(3/2)>>0`.

O `(3/2)&0` não serve porque a operação E com 0 tem sempre resultado 0, que não é o que queremos.

Caso o resultado não caiba num inteiro de 32-bits com sinal (complemento de dois), a divisão com truncatura ignora os restantes bits, pelo que o resultado pode ser diferente do esperado nesses casos ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c849q/7/)).

Caso estejamos perante uma divisão por zero, os métodos `floor`, `round`, `ceil` e `trunc` não alteram o resultado (devolvendo, portanto, infinito ou `NaN`), enquanto que a truncatura usando o `|0` dá resultado `0` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c849q/9/)).

Comment: Na minha opinião Math.Trunc é preferível. Para manter a compatibilidade com versões anteriores, eu faria uma função para utilizar na minha aplicação: `roundDivision = Math.Trunc || BitwiseOr;` Cujo argumento da função `BitwiseOr` também o número e o resultado seria `Arg | 0;`

Answer (score 7):

Mais explícito é com a função `Math.floor` (arredonda para baixo):

```
Math.floor(3/2)
> 1
```

Em alternativa, usar `parseInt`

```
parseInt(3/2) //ou parseInt(3/2, 10);
> 1
```

Comment: `parseInt` é para quando a entrada é string!

Answer (score 2):

O Javascript automaticamente já faz a divisão dando um resultado com decimal, porém você pode converter o resultado decimal em `Inteiro` para que você tenha o resultado que deseja.

## Exemplos:

Com decimal(**default**):

```
3/2;
=> 1.5
```

Inteiro(**com conversão**)

```
parseInt(3/2);
=> 1
```

Comment: Não faz sentido passar números para `parseInt`, a função é para strings!

Comment: Porque a `parseInt()` é pra strings ? qual seria a para float?

Comment: O que Luis Cubal sugeriu, um método de arredondamento ou truncamento com operador binário (por sinal, js não distingue int de float, é tudo `Number`). Qualquer coisa que você passe para `parseInt` é primeiro convertida para string (o que é um desperdício se a sua entrada é um número).

Comment: Entendi @bfavaretto porém eu não sabia disto. Não precisa gritar! haha.

Comment: Desculpe, é que eu gosto de JavaScript e às vezes sai informação demais :)

Comment: Sei como é que é, eu também sou um Lover do Javascript :P tem coisas que eu não me confooooooormo