# Pegar dados na página pelo javascript e converte-lo em inteiro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Esto com um problema, ao pegar um numero dentro de um span pelo javascript tento converte-lo em int com o parseInt, mas nada. Pois se tento fazer uma soma com outro numero ele acaba concatenado. e se eu converto com o parseInt ele aparece 'NAN'.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="qualquer"><span>5</span></div>
```

**Javascript com Jquery:**

```
numeroRecuperado = parseInt($('#qualquer span').text().replace(/[\d]/g, ''));
numeroQualquer = 5;

total = numeroRecuperado + numeroQualquer;

$("#qualquer span").text(total);
```

Como resultado ele aparece NAN.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta o código que você já tem.

Comment: Não tem nenhum espaço na string que você está tentando converter para inteiro? Talvez chamar a função .trim() na variável contendo o conteúdo do span resolva.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço uma divisão inteira?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6193/como-fa%c3%a7o-uma-divis%c3%a3o-inteira)

Comment: Nada a ver, não é duplicada! Galera coloquei o codigo

Comment: @RomarioPires dê um `console.log(numeroRecuperado)` e nos diga o que foi mostrado no *console*.

Comment: Seu código está errado. O seu código tira todos os números e deixa somente o que não é número no texto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percebo pelo seu código que existe um erro. Você usou a expressão regular `/[\d]/g`. Porém essa expressão regular faz com que seja capturado valores numéricos. Ou seja, você está pedindo pra substituir valores numéricos por nada.

Exemplo:

```js
document.write('teste 1 teste'.replace(/[\d]/g, ''));
```

A solução para seu problema seria fazendo algo assim:

```
var valor = document.querySelector('#id_do_span').innerHTML

var outro_valor = 15;

parseInt(valor) + outro_valor
```

Veja isso funcionando no [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rjk5zaeg/)

Se você quer utilizar expressões regulares para poder obter somente valores numéricos, utilize a expressão regular `\D+` (não numéricos).

Veja:

```js
var string = 'teste 15 teste';

document.write(string.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
```

**Sugestão**: Como sugestão, sugiro que você utilize os valores do `data` do `jQuery`. Você pode definir o valor `Number` normalmente lá, pois ele não é salvo como `String`. Assim você evita conversões de valores  desnecessárias.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function ()
{
    $('body').html($('#meu_span').data('number') + 3);
})
```

```html
<span id="meu_span" data-number='3'>3</span>
```

Comment: +1 e segue um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rjk5zaeg/) pra ajudar :)

Comment: Então fiz isso mas não deu, aparece NAN, olha o meu código agora na pergunta!

Comment: Veja se a edição te agrada. Coloquei uma opção com a expressãor regular.

Comment: Galera agora sei porque esta dando erro foi cagada minha, estou pegando nenhum valor do span agora que vi ¬¬. Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 3):

Segue a solução em cima de seu código:

```
numeroRecuperado = parseInt($('#qualquer span').text().replace(/\D/g,''));
numeroQualquer = 5;

total = numeroRecuperado + numeroQualquer;

$("#qualquer span").text(total);
```

segue [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/rjk5zaeg/2/)

Comment: Acho que corre o risco de ter caracteres não numéricos no `span`.

Comment: @jbueno, mas por si só o `parseInt` já não faz o trabalho de limpar os não-numéricos?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não tira não hehehe' cabei de testar :D

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Testei no `nodejs` e ele não fez isso.

Comment: Veja a **Sugestão** que dei na minha resposta. Usar o `data` é melhor do que pegar o valor do HTML. Já que estamos usando `jQuery`... que não estava nas tags da pergunta...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters realmente fica mais semântico e elegante :D

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar problemas de valores vazios eu uso dessa forma

```
numeroRecuperado = $('#qualquer span').text().replace(/\D/g, ''); // Remove o que não é número
numeroRecuperado = parseInt(numeroRecuperado) | 0; // o | 0 evita que uma falha na conversão retorne um NaN
numeroQualquer = 5;

total = numeroRecuperado + numeroQualquer;

$("#qualquer span").text(total);
```

Comment: Bacana, nem sabia disso :D